# How should I got about setting the auto layout / constraints for my iOS view via Storyboard?

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout, storyboard, uistackview

I am fairly new to setting up constraints for iOS views via Storyboard. I have built out the below view without constraints but have been having issues trying to figure out how to set the constraints for auto layout. It's not perfectly aligned, but the below view is the general idea I'm going for.

I have followed references and tutorials but am having trouble building out the below view as it is more complex than what tutorials I've seen go through. I can't figure out the specific approach I should go about to get the stacks and constrains set up to look similar to below to work on various screen sizes

I would appreciate if someone could help run down the approach of setting this up. It would definitely help with my understanding in how I should approach building out similar / more complex views in the future.

[image: App view without constraints]

I have tried to implement it via storyboard using the following layout shown below, but am getting confused on my approach and how the constraints should be set. I'm also unsure when UI elements should be placed only within a stack vs within a view.

[image: my attempt]

Comment: As a general rule, use a `UIStackView` when you have UI elements that would benefit from the way a stack view *arranges* its subviews, and use a `UIView` when not. It's difficult to say what (if anything) is wrong with your current attempt ... unless you show a screen-shot from another device and point out what is **not** looking the way you want it to look.

Answer (score 0):

Try to understand the basics of constraints

**Follow the step to achieve your Goal:(Do's and Dont's)**

1. Don't learn "stack_view" in the initial, it will confuse you lot.
2. Don't use Auto resizing (it feels uncomfortable on every new device design)
3. Learn simple Constraint, Ex: Leading,Trailing,Top & Botton.
4. Try to implement Constraint in multi views inside the view Controller
5. Learn how to make SizeToFit in the label based on content, Ex: Textview while typing it need to expand itself,And if a messge arrives a label auto size to fit the content.

**Then Next:**

1. implement the constraint to tableview and collectionview for inside the cells
2. learn to use Greater or lesser constant(sizeToFit) concept in button, label, view etc...
3. And learn the - horizontal, vertical in container..and bottom space to container.

This are the basic knowledge to learn in Constraints for both StoryBoard and Xib's.

After that moving to StackView is easy to understand.

**if you try to learn SwiftUI - StackView is must to Learn.**